# Repaints on Scroll populating input boxes

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I keep getting an orange box that says Repaints on Scroll in my input boxes. I don't know why I am getting it and would like to remove it. I am not sure if it is an issue with chrome. How do I fix this or remove it? I have restarted chrome and it keeps coming back.

[image]

Comment: It looks weird... But we need something more to help you, like a piece of code. If you want a weird solution, try something like `$('html').html(function(i, s){ return s.replace(/repaints on scroll/gi, ""); });`. Anyway *I think and hope* there is better solution :)

Comment: Put the link here then we can inspect

Comment: As note, chrome does not paint code or text by itself. That text is part of something that you have in your code. @LGVentura has a better idea than mine. Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: your chrome puts it on all sites containing input boxes?

Comment: Yes its on all my input boxes. I turned off all my extensions and restarted chrome. That seems to work. I looked at the same page with Mozilla and I didn't get the same issue. I can't really provide a link it is on my localhost. I could post the js file. It is really odd.

Comment: Which chrome extensions do you have? Could you list here?

Comment: Edit this Cookie and JSON Formatter

Comment: The problem continues to persist. Removing the extensions didn't work.

Comment: I still thinking that you have something in your code that causes it. Try to do a file search looking for that text inside on all files in your project. You should find it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a debug feature of Chrome you seem to have turned on without noticing.
In the Developer Tools window look for a tab called 'Rendering' It's down by the console so you'll want to have that visible first.
In the rendering tab there are some check boxes, one of which will be 'Show potential scroll bottlenecks' Uncheck that and the boxes will be gone.

Comment: That's it. I just stumbled on it! Thank you so much.

Comment: I didn't find this tab. :(

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli you have to act as if you are opening the console. Click on the console icon and then it'll be among the four tabs: "Console, Search, Emulation, Rendering"